# Unsetting max-width:100% and height:auto;

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

In my project all images inside a container have the css attributes `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` to scale images down when the viewport shrinks and the container shrinks.
This is working, but the price to pay is that the browser is not able to draw the page correctrly without loading the images to get the dimensions.
When I embed the image via `<img  width=100 height=100 />` the browser normaly reserves the space and renders the rest of the page.
As soon as the above mentioned css is applied, the site content below the image “jumps” because the image is 0x0px during load progress.
This leads me to two questions:

1. Is there a way to use the max-with 100/height auto technique without destroying the normal placeholder behavior?
2. If not, what would be a correct class declaration to apply for some of the images that should *not* auto-resize and loaded normally, with correct sized placeholder during load? I tried `height: initial` and `height: inherit`, in both attempts the image is still 0x0px before loaded, the html `height` attribute is ignored.

I created a fiddle, but the loading problem cannot be seen here due to caching; Therefore, I copied the code from https://jsfiddle.net/yrx52avq/4/ to http://www.testserver01.de/fiddle.php and added delays and no-caching options.
Reload the page: The red boxes pop out during load progress. The green ones do not.
[image: Before and after fully loaded images]

Comment: You could use the standard height/width placeholder technique initially and have some JavaScript execute on window load that attaches a class to the images with the override styles. Not sure there's any way to achieve it in pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In your css, please try the below code using the property `object-fit:cover` or `object-fit:contain`. This property will resize your image to fit in the container.

```
.container img {
  object-fit:cover;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

or

```
.container img {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

you can find more information on object-fit property from the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)

Comment: This does not work in the given construct. 
Beside this, neither IE nor Edge is supported.